# How do I start and install Ubuntu from USB flash drive

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm replacing Windows 10 with Ubuntu. I downloaded Rufus and put the Ubuntu IOS on a flash drive.

I've rebooted my computer and clicked into the Ubuntu file on the flash drive.

I find several files with names like ".disk," "boot" and "install."

From here, I cannot figure out how to install. I would appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you.

Todd

Comment: You may want to see if there is a local Linux user group near you. They should be able to help you install

Answer (score 2):

**1. Boot to the Ubuntu's bootable media**

You need to boot to the USB, do this by acessing BIOS at your computer startup, by pressing key *x* (consult your computer vendor for more details) and then, select your flash drive at boot options. After this, just press enter when you are seeing the GRUB bootloader. Next, wait some time and you will see your Ubuntu desktop.

**2. Install Ubuntu**

Simply click on the icon called "Install Ubuntu" that is at your desktop, which launches Ubuntu's automated GUI installer, called "ubiquity". Then just install it.

Comment: It's also important to write the USB as a disk image and not simply to copy the ISO file, or whatever, to the USB's existing partitions. `unetbootin`, [`rufus`](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and similar applications enable this. Then as Chexier says, reboot ensuring that your computer is booting from the USB drive.

Comment: Cool. I figured out how to get to BIOS and edited my boot options to make sure it's booting from the USB, though the machine seems to stop at that point. I'll keep trying...maybe a different USB? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are replacing. Just do the erase disk and install Ubuntu, if you have multiple drives, they let you choose which drive.

Also, make sure you edit your boot option from your bios to boot from a USB, it's based on your motherboard so look it up. Make sure you installed the usb corectly with soemthing like UNetbootin :
http://unetbootin.github.io/

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5

If you are dual booting follow this.
http://dailylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html